# Visual Studio\Python -How to move multiple code lines to right

Tags: visual-studio

Sorry for the silly question, but i'm trying to move my code right but doing it line by line.

Lets say my code is

```
if x==0:
    print a
else:
    if x==3:
```

and lets say i want to add new "if" in the begining of the code i need to take all my code right
so the new code will look like:

```
if y==3:
    print y
else:
     if x==0:
           print a
     else:
          if x==3:
```

as for today i'm pressing "space" several time on each line to set it in the right place

I know that "ALT" and arrow take it up\down but coudnt fine the left right if there is something like that

thanks

Comment: You can select all the lines you want to format and press `Ctrl+K,Ctrl+F` to auto format it.

Comment: try ctrl+f and ctrl+k after selecting the code snippet, this should indent the code

Answer (score 1):

Either move it line-by-line with `TAB`, or select several lines and use `TAB`. You can move them in the other direction with `Shift+TAB`. As already suggested you can also use `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F` to auto-format.

In the visual studio settings you can decide whether the spacing consist of tab symbols or actual blank spaces and the number. Keep this in mind, as some file types don't like one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the Q answers.I'm using the Tab :), altougho it didnt work for me the crrl k and than ctrl f.I added the "if" at the begining of the code, choose all code and than ctrl k, ctrl f but it did nothing -am i missing somthing here?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to move the whole code 1 tab space

Comment: [@MartijnK’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595325/3025856) from over five years ago already gives the same advice, but with additional information and clarity. (`Shift`+`Tab` unindents, which is clearer in the previous answer.) What is this answer adding that hasn’t been covered before?